# View model data annotation vs Index method model data annotation parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

This is kind of confusing to me. The controller method Index was receiving an object parameter from my model library which has it's own data annotation specifications like the signature below:

`public ActionResult Index(vwClient Registro = null)`

but my Index was returning an ActionResult with a different object model created just to fill the view necessities and it has some properties with the same name of the parameter Registro but different data annotation attributes:

```
ViewModel.Registro MyViewModel = new ViewModel.Registro();
return View(MyViewModel);
```

and my view is expecting a model of ViewModel.Registro type:

`ViewModel.Registro`

Here comes the problem. The data annotation attributes of the ViewModel.Registro has been completely ignored (DisplayFor, ValidationMessageFor). The data annotation specification was coming from vwClient. If I change the parameter type to object the problem stops:

`public ActionResult Index(object Registro = null)`

Does someone know what am I missing here? And please, don't ask me why I am doing this. I just want to understand this MVC behavior.

---

Here goes the code of the classes as example:

```
//it comes from my model library. Note here the id property is marked as Required
public class vwClient
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Client")]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public DateTime dateCreation { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company")]
    public SelectList CompanyList { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Client")]
    public SelectList ClientList { get; set; }
}

//here is the other class used as model by the view
public class Registro
{
    [DisplayName("Client")]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public DateTime dateCreation { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company")]
    public SelectList CompanyList { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Client")]
    public SelectList ClientList { get; set; }
}
```

Now the Index method of the controller. When I declare Registro as vwClient I got problem.

```
public ActionResult Index(vwClient Registro = null)
{
    MyViewModel.Registro MyViewModel = new ViewModel.Registro();
    return View(MyViewModel);
}
```

Now the Index method of the controller which the problem was fixed by declaring Registro as object.

```
public ActionResult Index(object Registro = null)
{
    MyViewModel.Registro MyViewModel = new ViewModel.Registro();
    return View(MyViewModel);
}
```

---

Here goes a partial code of the view as example:

```
@model ViewModel.Registro
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="form-control-wrapper">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id, selectList: (SelectList)Model.ClientList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"}, optionLabel: string.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Please, let me know if the problem is clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "The data annotation attributes of the ViewModel.Registro has been completely ignored. Just the vwClient is being applied"?

Comment: I agree, post ViewModel

Comment: I was talking about the DisplayFor and ValidationMessageFor.

Comment: @AndreRB are those the two Index methods HttpGet? or HttpPost?

Comment: @fiorebat, check my post again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user449689, they are HttpGet and sometimes I use it to return to default view from HttpPost action methods.

Comment: A GET method should not have a model as a parameter. And since your not even using it then just remove it. Since both your models have identical `[Display]` attributes, your claim that `DisplayFor()` is ignored makes no sense, and in any case, no where in your code do you even use  `DisplayFor()` (I assume you mean `LabelFor()`?).

Comment: As for the error message you get on the `id` property its because you have added the `vwClient` model as a parameter therefore the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes an instance of `vwClient`, then adds a `ModelState` error associated with property `id` (because its `null` and has the `[Required]` attribute) which is then rendered in the view because your view as a property for `id`

Comment: Wait.. [DisplayName(..)] are not working?
why you don't have  ModelState.IsValid? have you got in select (drop drown list) an empty option (looking html source)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, I mean LabelFor and I'd declared a Get method that could receive a model as parameter. It worked but it gave me other problems like triggering the validation after loading the page. The second problem is in the topic, the data annotation attributes considered by LabelFor, ValidationMessageFor, EditorFor... wasn't that one specified in the beginning of the view or passed as a parameter in the return of the Action method. The data annotation attributes came from the variable in the method signature. I need to study more about MVC behavior/ architecture to understand it.

Comment: Do **not** use a model as a parameter in a GET method (because it adds `ModelState` errors which is why you get the error in the view (and you don't even appear to be using it so what is the point?). And I have no idea what trying to say in the second part of you comment :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke hahaha, I have problem to explain it in my native language imagine in a foreign language. I tried to explain it in my question. Take a look to the model declaration in the view. It's typed as ViewModel.Registro which the Data Annotation attributes are different from ViewClient (parameter declared in the Index method signature). Is it clear until here?

Comment: The data annotations are **identical** except for the `[Required]` on the `id` property of `vwClient` (so, no, its not clear what your trying to say).

Comment: @StephenMuecke, there is not problem to be similar. If I change the DisplayName for something else the problem is the same. What I could understand why the data annotation attributes of the method signature (ViewClient) was being evaluated and not the view model type (@model ViewModel.Registro).

Comment: What? If you change attribute of the `id` property to `[DisplayName("XXX")]`, then `@LabelFor(m => m.id)` will display "XXX" not "Client". And I have already explained why you see the error message in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that's the problem. The LabelFor is displaying "Client" (specified in ViewClient) not "XXX" (specified in ViewModel.Registro). Yes, you have already explained that I should not do it.

Comment: Nonsense. If it is, you doing something else wrong that you have not shown us.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have no time to do it now but later I will upload a project showing the problem. Maybe while doing this I discover what I was doing wrong. Indeed it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Muecke said in his comment:

> Do not use a model as a parameter in a GET method (because it adds ModelState errors which is why you get the error in the view (and you don't even appear to be using it so what is the point?). And I have no idea what trying to say in the second part of you comment :) – Stephen Muecke Nov 19 at 10:51

It totally explained my problem. Thanks for the help.